# How to create a bar graph in Excel 2010 by counts?

Tags: excel, graph

For whatever reason I can't get this to work right.

I have a column of values, say lots of A's, B's, C's, and D's.

I want to make a graph that shows "Here's how many A's we have, here's how many B's we have, here's how many C's we have, here's how many D's we have.

For some reason I do Insert -> 3d Column graph, and then I try to select the values in the column (A2 to A(some big number)), but it's like it doesn't want to count anything. It's trying to put all the values in the title of the graph, like "A B A C D A B..." and same with the legend, and then the bar graph itself just shows one flat-category at level 0. It makes zero sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read on usage of [pivot charts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotChart-C1B1E057-6990-4C38-B52B-8255538E7B1C):

[image]

**Procedure:**

Pivot Table:

- Select Data
- Insert Pivot Chart
- Drag Value field to Row area and also to Data Area as Count of Value

Chart:

- Select Pivot Table
- Insert Column Chart

Comment: Take that back: I see it now. Pivot Chart is not part of the Chart section. Thanks! :)

Comment: I downvoted your answer because you didn't answer the question but only linked to an external resource, one which is applicable to Excel 2013 while the user asked about Excel 2010. From the FAQ: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." I'll undo my downvote if you edit and provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Starfish This technique is relevant to all versions of Excel since the introduction of Pivot Tables, so this should not be a consideration. I understand downvoting for providing a link only with no explanation, especially a link to Microsoft documentation. I've added a brief procedure.

Comment: @JonPeltier Thank you for the edit. I assumed making pivots were easy enough and doesn't need step by step guide.

Comment: @Starfish the link is not specific to version of Excel, plus Jon added description, too. Please re-consider your votes.

Comment: @JonPeltier Thanks for adding the clarification. I've changed to an upvote.