# Pivot Chart - Create a Bin Counting Bar or Pie Chart in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba

I've never created a Pivot Table before. Back when I learned how to get around in Microsoft Excel, there was no such thing.

I'm trying to follow the tutorial in this post:

[How to create a bar graph in Excel 2010 by counts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20076802/153923)

But my Pivot Chart is blank.

I'm just trying to create a simple Bar or Pie Chart to show how many tickets each of our members have sold.

The tickets are numbered. At first, it started simple: Everyone was assigned a consecutive number of tickets (like 1-20, 21-40, etc), then some of our group started outselling others.

Now, tickets 1-7 might have been sold by the same person, but 8, 15, 18, and 19 were handed off and sold by someone else.

I can keep up with it in my Excel spreadsheet, but coming up with a way to display how many tickets each person has sold is proving tricky.

I could probably have this done already if I'd use my fingers and toes, but I want this to be done on the PC, and using Excel.

Here's a screenshot showing how far I've gotten. I had to blur the names, because a lot of our members think the Internet is the devil. Maybe it is, but that's a different topic. :)

[image: screenshot]

Could someone walk me through how to get a chart to show all of our members (like Wade with 40 or so, Allan with 20, and Dennis with 0)?

If a VBA solution is more suited for this, I'd be happy to see how to go about getting one of those to work as well.

Comment: have you tried putting anything in the Values section of the PivotTable Field List? That section is what shows up on the chart. The Axis field will only be the labels for the Axis.

Comment: How? Drag-N-Drop doesn't seem to do anything, and there is no Right-Click menu. ...OH! I just saw Captain's post - Drag from the Field List. OK. Not very intuitive, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag `Sold` into the `Values` (assuming that it is a 0 or 1 for if the ticket they have is sold or not)...
(Pivots are a great tool - I recommend playing with a Pivot Table and then making a Pivot Chart... it is easier to see what is going on, in my opinion)

Comment: Thank you! That just did not seem intuitive to me at all!