# How to create a count table of two variables in excel pivot

Tags: excel, pivot

I am struggling with creating a count table of two variables at the same time. Ultimately, I would like to create a bar graph of the table.

Assuming I have two items for a sample of firms and I just want a summary table of the answer count.

```
Firm       Item1    Item2
1          1        1
2          2        1
3          1        2
4          1        2
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076802/how-to-create-a-bar-graph-in-excel-2010-by-counts), I can easily create the summary table for Item 1 telling me that "1" appears three times for item 1 and two times in Item 2. But I cant easily create a Pivot table showing this jointly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood correct, but is it `COUNTIF()` you need?

In D1 type:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B, "1")
```

that should give you result `3`

Comment: Thanks, I specifically would like to use the built in Pivot function. I can use the pivot approach described in my link for one variable, but not two at the same time.